# PHP email not sent

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I use this code to send an email:

When I open the `mail.php` file in my browser. Nothing will send. The browser will load a blank page with no message displayed saying the email was sent.  I have been searching on StackOverflow and other websites for a solution.  Can someone help me?

```
<?php

require_once("phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php"); 
// path to the PHPMailer class.

require_once("phpmailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php");


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";


$mail->Port = "25"; 
// 8025, 587 and 25 can also be used. Use Port 465 for SSL.

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
// Uncomment this line if you want to use SSL.

$mail->Username = "emailer@my.domain";
$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->From     = "example@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Susan Sender";
$mail->AddAddress("rachel@my.domain", "Rachel Recipient");
//$mail->AddReplyTo("Your Reply-to Address", "Sender's Name");

$mail->Subject  = "Hi!";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! How are you?";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;  

if(!$mail->Send()) 
{
    echo 'Message was not sent.';
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
} 
else {
        echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Activate error messages by adding the follow at the top of the script (after `<?php`): `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois  I got this after adding that:   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013) 2015-02-12 20:36:00 SMTP connect() failed. Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: There you have it. Wrong login credentials.

Comment: Login credentials?  I have used smtp.gmail.com  and have used my gmail account and password to send the email.  I tried that.  It didn't work.

Comment: Why are you even trying to use authentication without encryption, especially to gmail, which won't tolerate such foolishness? How about you [start with some recent code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) instead of the obsolete example you're using?

Comment: @Synchro  I am new to email.  I don't know what I am doing.

Comment: @Syncrho Not email entirely, just coding with it.  Could php.ini file be wrong?

Comment: First of all try that example I pointed you at. PHP.ini should not have much bearing on that.

Comment: Change `$mail->Port = "25"; ` to `$mail->Port = "465";`.  Then uncomment the line `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`.  That should solve the problem.

Comment: @mti2935  That didn't work.

Comment: @Synchro  I get Could not instantiate mail function and message is not sent.

Comment: I have tried everything so far.  I don't understand.

Comment: If you get that error, you're not using the example I suggested.

Comment: @Synchro  Do I have to install sendmail?

Comment: No. When you're sending via SMTP you don't need a local mail server at all.

Comment: @Synchro  Something is wrong then.  I am using your example.  I still get the could not instantiate mail function.

Comment: You are not using the example I pointed you at. Your code uses much older syntax and contains mistakes.

Comment: @Synchro I have used the code in your example.

Comment: You're doing something very basic wrong then - that error can only be generated if you call `mail()`, and that does not happen if you're using `isSMTP()`, as that example does.

Comment: @Synchro   Update.  I am getting this error:  SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)
SMTP connect() failed.
Not sent SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: [Read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)